# In a for loop something responding as an error when in a variable but when not in a variable it is normal

Tags: javascript

So I am attempting to code a chess board with the limited knowledge that I have and I have been surprisingly successful. But there has been something weird.

In a for loop that I have to check all the possible moves and narrow it down (I know not the most efficient, but I'm trying to do this with as little help as possible). What I'm doing is basically going through a couple arrays to try to do it.

And when I do

```
  for (i = 0; i < legalMoves.length; i++) {
    if (legalMoves[i] > 63 || legalMoves[i] < 0) {
      legalMoves.splice(i, 1)
      i--
    }
      console.log(squareInfo[legalMoves[i]][2]) // line to pay attention to
  }
```

It works perfectly as expected, but when I do

```
  for (i = 0; i < legalMoves.length; i++) {
    lM = squareInfo[legalMoves[i]] // variable to pay attention to
    if (legalMoves[i] > 63 || legalMoves[i] < 0) {
      legalMoves.splice(i, 1)
      i--
    }
      console.log(lM[2]) // line to pay attention to
  }
```

The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined`

Which is really weird.

Somethings to note is that my arrays contain no undefined characters, and when I run it without the variable it works perfectly and as expected.

Does anyone know why this would happen, as being able to use the lM variable would make things a lot easier for this process.

### To clarify, the question is why is the same thing when in a variable coming out as an error.

Comment: Are you using `strict` mode?

Comment: You are modifying `i` after when you initialize the `lM` but in your previous code, i was modified before logging on the console. So please initialize the `lM` below if condition.

Comment: This code is also super confusing due to both incrementing and decrementing `i` within the loop as well as mutating the `legalMoves` array which you are iterating

Comment: @swapnilbandiwadekar Yes, Thank you that fixed it.

Comment: just doing it below the `if` condition is not enough as the next `legalMoves` item might also be outside the **1**-**63** range. The whole `lM = ...` and the `console.log` should be in an `else` to be sure.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tradis, The way you are using array to store in separate variable is the real problem. In Javascript, when you use simple variable javascript actually create new memory space and assign it to that memory space.

1. But when you are assigning array or object to new javascript variable, it just make a reference to that specific variable, not make a copy of that variable.
2. So, when you assign your array to variable `IM` and then you delete the i from your actual array. So, `IM` became undefined, because that specific index is being removed.
3. The actual issue is in your if condition, you can check it by commenting the if condition.
4. If you really want to use this variable technique, please use deep copy to make an actual copy of your `legalMoves` array.

Comment: Yes thank you, I had realized this in the comments and it makes a lot more sense now. I appreciate your time :)!!!

Comment: Another way that I can do it is just inserting a ```continue;``` in there where I'm reducing ```i```. Would you suggest that?

Comment: No the `lM` did not suddenly become undefined because the `i` changed. The `lM` is already initialized and is not altered. The problem is that the `legalMoves[i]` was not existing in the `squareInfo` in the first place.

Comment: Yes so would removing the non existing ```legalMoves[i]``` element, and then doing a ```continue;``` fix it, so then it could sit at the top again. Because after figuring out that a move is wrong, I don't need to keep doing check, I can just continue.

Comment: Just did it, in my code, and it worked exactly how I wanted it too and sped it up.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli The real problem you see  is at this line `legalMoves.splice(i, 1)` that specific index is removed from squareInfo, at which `IM` is being defined as `squareInfo[legalMoves[i]]`. Since, `IM` is just a reference that is why it is showing undefined.

Comment: @HamidR. nope. `squareInfo` !== `legalMoves`. The splice remove a value from `legalMoves`. The `squareInfo` is not affected and nor is the already initialized `lM`.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli please see issue yourself in the given codepen. https://codepen.io/r-hamid/pen/gOWmwBJ?editors=1011
If you direct your attention towards console. You can see that `IM` is undefined. You see the execution of `if` condition will make `IM` undefined.

Comment: @HamidR. you will see the same result if you move the `console.log` above the `splice` so you can understand that the `splice `has nothing to do with it. The problem is that you are accessing the `7th` element of an array with no that many contents.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Ohh I see. You are right. It is a single index that has been assigned. There shouldn't be any issue in my codepen. My bad

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that your `lM` is initialized with the `i` that has the *wrong* value, since that `legalMoves[i]` is not accepted.

You should do the `lM = ...` part only when the i passes the check.

```
 for (i = 0; i < legalMoves.length; i++) {
    if (legalMoves[i] > 63 || legalMoves[i] < 0) {
      legalMoves.splice(i, 1)
      i--
    } else {
      lM = squareInfo[legalMoves[i]] // variable to pay attention to
      console.log(lM[2]) // line to pay attention to
    }
  }
```

---

But a better approach would be to remove the *invalid* values from the `legalMoves` array **before** the loop so you do not have to do this tricks in a loop.

```js
const onlyLegalMoves = legalMoves.filter((move) => (move >= 0 && move <= 63));

for (i = 0; i < onlyLegalMoves.length; i++) {
  const legalMove = onlyLegalMoves[i];
  console.log(squareInfo[legalMove][2]) // line to pay attention to
}
```

---

Finally if you only want to find the first really valid move, you could just use `.find` instead of the whole loop.

```js
const moveToUse = legalMoves.find( (move) => (move >= 0 && move <= 63) );
console.log( squareInfo[moveToUse][2] );
```